# Is the Schunk powerball package working? Always get an error

Tags: ros, care-o-bot, schunk

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to get my powerball up and running with a Peak USB to Can module.
But when I want to start the modules, I always get this error:

```
initstring = PCAN:/dev/pcan32,500000
PCanDevice successfully opened on /dev/pcan32
Initializing pcan device ...
PcanDevice, init ok
[ INFO] [1352452510.964341600]: ...initializing powercubes not successful. error:         
Could not reset module 5, m5api error code: -207
```

Can someone tell me if this package is working or what I am doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47864/is-the-schunk-powerball-package-working?-always-get-an-error./) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2012-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The communication of the new **SCHUNK Powerball LWA 4.6** arm is based on CANOpen. The old m5api (Schunk Motion Protocol 5) is not supported!

There is a very new canopen package [ipa_canopen](https://github.com/ipa320/ipa_canopen). I've got the test commands running (ipa_canopen_core/tools/move_device) - still need to configure the rospackage for the SCHUNK arm. Device IDs are 3/4 (Cube1) 5/6 (Cube2), 7/8 (Cube3) and 12 for the Gripper (using WSG-50). The ipa_canopen package only supports PCAN (PEAK CAN) devices at the moment (we use a pcan-usb-can adapter).

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [kglatz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3721/kglatz/) with karma: 36 on 2012-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2012-12-07**:
I was told that the ROS wrapper should be available in the next days.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The -207 error code stands for a CAN write error. This usually means that something is wrong with the driver configuration, the configuration file or with the communication's physical connection.

As the error appeared in module 5, it should mean that the program was able to reset all the other 4 modules, so your driver configuration should be fine. So, it either means that your robot only has 4 modules or that there's something wrong with your fifth module.

By something wrong, it could be the physical connection problem I said before: disconnected cables, power supply issues and so on. It could also be caused by a wrong moduleID configuration, in which you tried reaching a moduleID that isn't connected to the CAN Bus.

---

Originally posted by [Murilo Marinho](https://answers.ros.org/users/3560/murilo-marinho/) with karma: 11 on 2012-11-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1